# How to get data from Promise_ object?

Tags: react-native, console, local-storage, asyncstorage

I'm trying to get some data from a **Promise_** object, in *React Native* app, in my AsyncStorage.

This is what I get in the console, in my Promise_ object :

```
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
  _40: 0
  _55: {imageId: "1", imageName: "test.png"}
  _65: 1
  _72: null
__proto__: Object
```

So I don't know how to simply get the data in the *_55* and show them in my code, I just want to take "1" and "test.png".
And sorry for my bad english. Thanks !

**CODE :**

This is the code for the set : 
`export const setBadgePicture = async (badgePictureId, badgePictureName) => await AsyncStorage.multiSet([['imageId', badgePictureId],['imageName', badgePictureName]])`

and for the get :
`export const getBadgePicture = async () => { await AsyncStorage.multiGet(['imageId', 'imageName']).then((response) => { tableResponse = { 'imageId' : response[0][1], 'imageName' : response[1][1], } }) return tableResponse }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this to wait until your AsyncStorage returns the item.

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem('YOUR_KEY').then((response)=>{
      const itemVal = response;
})
```

Comment: can we use promise function like that 
AsyncStorage.getItem('data').
then(response => response.json()).then((response)=>{ const itemVal = response });

Comment: you can use call .then() only with the functions that return promise, AsyncStorage.getItem returns a promise but not . then() :D

Comment: can you add me .

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` `getItem` function is an Asynchronous function. That means that if you want to get the return of that "get" function you will have to wait for the response. if you are using `AsyncStorage.getItem()` function add the reserved word `await` before the statement and in the function you are calling it put the reserved word `async` like this way:

```
async myFunctionWhereImCallingTheGetter () {
  var myData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('theitemIamSearching');
}
```

Comment: ad then as an option too. :)

Comment: Sure! It's another option but I think that's more clearly to face at first time

Comment: I tried your solution but still not work for me @MtgKhaJeskai

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai no error, juste the same result whit 'Promise_'

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai This is the code for the set : 

`export const setBadgePicture = async (badgePictureId, badgePictureName) => await AsyncStorage.multiSet([['imageId', badgePictureId],['imageName', badgePictureName]])`

and for the get :

`export const getBadgePicture = async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.multiGet(['imageId', 'imageName']).then((response) => {
    tableResponse = {
      'imageId' : response[0][1],
      'imageName' : response[1][1],
    }
  })
  return tableResponse
}`

Comment: Try to post it in the asking not in this comment. And try to return tableRespose inside the then()

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai I post the code in the question, and the return tableResponse in the "then" doesn't work

Comment: Using async/await has a worse performance than then/catch. Please see this graphic from Google V8 engineer `https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/1097052396587380736`

Answer (score 0):

Try then that:

```
export const getBadgePicture = async () => {
  var response = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(['imageId', 'imageName']);
  var tableResponse = { 'imageId' : response[0][1], 'imageName' : response[1][1], } });
  return tableResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you avoid multiGet?

```
export const getBadgePicture = async () => {
  var imageId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('imageId');
  var imageName = await AsyncStorage.getItem('imageName');
  var tableResponse = { 'imageId' : imageId, 'imageName' : imageName };
  return tableResponse;
}
```

Comment: Are you logging the tableResponse? have you checked and logged imageId and imageName vars? In that case, could you post the logs?

Comment: If that still failing you will have to check the code that is calling that functions due to I don't really think that the problem would be that functions we have provided you